# Jsr303 specify group on association validation

Tags: bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am facing an issue when validating object which has more than one relationship to bean of particular type but each of relationship must be validated in a different manner.
Composite class:

```
public class Composite{
  @Valid
  private Person insurer;
  @Valid
  private Person insured;
  ...(other properties)
  private String foo;
}
```

Person class:

```
public class Person{
@NotNull(groups={Insurer.class,Insured.class})
private String name;
@NotNull(groups={Insurer.class,Insured.class})
private String surname;
...
@NotNull(groups={Insurer.class})
private String ssn;
}
```

So we have a single type Person which can represent insurer and insured. The problem is that when validating Composite i want to have insurer property to be validated with Insurer group and insured with Insured. Is there anyway it can be accomplished or i need to wait for https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/BVAL-208 resolving...

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue in a standardized way you indeed have to wait for Bean Validation 1.1 which will address BVAL-208 (group translations).

In case your *Person* class also has a flag or some other criteria you could use to determine whether this person is an insurer or insured you could also use a custom class level constraints. The downside is that you are loosing some of the expressiveness of annotations, since you would have to do all validation yourself in the custom constraint validator implementation.

The other alternative (again you need a way to distinguish between insurer and insured) is to use the Hibernate Validator specific [*GroupSequenceProvider*](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-default-group-class). This way you can keep your current configuration and you just would return the right group depending on the type of *Person*.

Comment: thx for the answer. Actually none of these workaround would be really good. I could introduce some transient "insured/insurer" flag but i ended up with manual validation of insurer/insured properties, null both of them in composite, validate composite, merge (with prefix)insurer/insured  and composite violations.